# Javascript Dialogue box in ctp?

Tags: javascript, cakephp

In test.ctp file

```
<?php   echo $form->create(null, array('url' => 'test/'.$test['Test']['id'], 'onSubmit'=>'return status(this)')); ?>

<?php   echo $form->hidden('id', array('value' => $test['Test']['id'])); ?>

<dl class="editForm">
    <?php echo $form->create(null, array('url' => 'test/'.$test['Test']['id'])); ?>
    <?php echo $form->hidden('id', array('value' => $test['Test']['id'])); ?>

    <dt><label><?php __('Update Status');?>:</label></dt>
    <dd><?php echo $form->select('status_id', $statuses, $selectedStatus, array(), false); ?></dd>

    <dd><?php  echo $form->end(__('Update Status', true));  ?></dd>
    </dl>
```

In the same .ctp file I need a dialogue box to appear when update button is clicked for confirmation that if user wants to continue with "No Status" or not?
Following code is not working for me, where I am not getting status_id value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function status() {

        var status_id = $("#status_id").val();
        alert(status_id);

    }

</script>
```

Required: If status_id value is 1 in posted data then dialogue box should appear for confirmation.

Comment: Are you sure that the id is status_id? i am not sure, but i think cake names element differently.

Comment: Here status_id is different than id.

Comment: Probably Cake is changing the id for something like `StatusId`. So check the select's id in the output html or add an `id` field in the options array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To create one button you don't need to keep create a new form.** by using form->create...

what you want is just to check the dropdown if the value equals 1 confirmation_window appears.
To do so first you have to know the basic of HTML and JS. if you could implement that you will be able to do so. convert the code blow to cakephp tagging and form. it will get it work.

```
<form onsubmit="status();" >
    <select name="data[User][field]" id="UserField">
       <option value="0">1</option>
       <option value="1">2</option>
       <option value="2">3</option>        
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>


<script>
    function status() {    
        var status_id = $("#UserField").val();
        //or
        var status_id = document.getElemetById("UserField");
        alert(status_id.options[status_id.selectedIndex].value);
    }    
</script>
```

you could even assign id_name to your dropdown. then you should be able to get the value from dropdown using js or jQuery.

```
$form->select('status_id', array('id'=>'status_id')); ?>
```